# Azure SQL database make AD user see more databases in SSMS

Tags: permissions, azure-sql-database, users

I'm using Azure SQL databases and want to add a user from my company using Active Directory auth, so adding the user from external provider.

The problem - by design Azure SQL creates AD users as contained database users and they can't see any database in SSMS besides the one they have specifically connected to, unless if they have a user in the `master` database, when they see **all** databases, even ones they don't have a user in.

My goal:

To make it so basic users (i.e. non-technical users that shouldn't have any more permissions other than `select` and the like) can connect to the server using AD auth in SSMS and see all databases they have a user created in.

Since Azure doesn't allow that by default, I'm looking for a workaround that can achieve that and would allow me to NOT create a user in the master database OR create a user in master with NO permissions in master for the users.

Comment: did you make any progress on this? I'm interested in something similar

Comment: @CervEd, none whatsoever. From all the knowledge I gained about Azure I'd say this is impossible. Along with a myriad of other super basic and useful features.